# django password hash different everytime

Tags: django, hash, passwords

if I create a hash using django's django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password of the same string I get different hash every time. I don't understand how is this legal because as far as I know, hash functions must generate the same hash every time since by definition its a function. What am I missing?

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
password = "helloworld"
h1 = make_password(password)
h2 = make_password(password)
print h1, h2
```

*h1 = u'pbkdf2_sha256$20000$Tr6NV5MewXYl$X+sezT6WRqBwYmJR/RZmZHLP6/l6ntSaBke0RKU1/v0='*

*h2 = u'pbkdf2_sha256$20000$05rEmxChtXlI$NdZGfTKH+kqt1viuFng3GmvBp6eJcsstxV4JcDlBGIs='*

I suspect that different algorithms are used to hash every time and hence the hash is also different. Am I correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see different results because of the [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)). In simple words Django add some random string to the password before hashing to get different values even for same password. This makes [`rainbaw tables`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attack are useless. Actually what you see in DB is not plain hash value, it's structure in following format: `<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>`

Answer (score 8):

Each time you use `make_password`, the password is hashed with a different salt. Django stores the salt with the hashed password. You can then use [`check_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password) to check the password later.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password, make_password
password = "helloworld"
h1 = make_password(password)
check_password(password, h1)  # returns True
check_password("incorrect", h1)  # returns False
```

Read the docs on [how Django stores passwords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password) for more info.